# Flutter Elevated Button - How do I remove elevation with MaterialStateProperty.all?

Tags: flutter, elevation

Ok, with the new flutter updates I have figured out most things, but I can't seem to figure out what the elevated property wants. I have applied MaterialStateProperty.all and the property is asking for a positional argument but I don't know what it wants. I have tried double, elevatedValue and everything else predictable but I can not discern how to set this to zero. Can someone please provide a code example of the new Elevated Button with the elevation set to zero using MaterialStateProperty please?

Comment: If you don't want your button to be _elevated_, have you considered using [`OutlinedButton`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/OutlinedButton-class.html) instead of `ElevatedButton`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is how you use new `Elevated button`

```
ElevatedButtonThemeData(
      style: ButtonStyle(
        backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
          (Set<MaterialState> states) {
            if (states.contains(MaterialState.disabled)) {
              return greyColor;
            }
            return selectedPrimaryColor; // Defer to the widget's default.
          },
        ),
        elevation: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<double>(  // As you said you dont need elevation. I'm returning 0 in both case
              (Set<MaterialState> states) {
            if (states.contains(MaterialState.disabled)) {
              return 0;
            }
            return 0; // Defer to the widget's default.
          },
        ),
        foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
          (Set<MaterialState> states) {
            if (states.contains(MaterialState.disabled)) {
              return greyColor;
            }
            return selectedPrimaryColor; // Defer to the widget's default.
          },
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Btw I extract this  from themeData. So that I don't need to repeat the code again and again. You should also learn ThemeData class. [Here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData-class.html) is the docs.

Comment: Perfect! Thank-you, I didn't realize I had to go to this much code for every single property. For some reason I kept thinking this one wouldn't need all of that. Thank-you for clarifying.

Answer (score 3):

Another cleaner approach from the accepted answer is to use `styleFrom` method:

```dart
ElevatedButton(
  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(elevation: 0),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways available but this will provide more customization for the border so this is worthwhile to use this one.

```
style: ButtonStyle(
      elevation: MaterialStateProperty.all(0),
      shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
              RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero),
             ),
       ),
```